# Como puedo guardar en una variable los resultado de una promesa

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Tengo una duda acerca de cómo  puedo guardar los **results** en una variable, para poder mostrar en el html los resultados por separado, el monto y el total.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**agenda.servicio**

```
async getEstado(){
    
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'x-token': this.usuarioService.token,
      'a-token': this.tokenA

    });


    return new Promise( resolve => {
      this.http.get(`${URL}/agenda/estado/`, { headers })
      .subscribe( resp => {
      console.log(resp);

      if ( resp['ok'] ) {

        resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }

      });

    });

  }
```

Comment: Te haz topado con una de las peores cosas que tiene javascript (y ojo, yo uso solo javascript y otras pocas tecnologias de vez en cuando, asi que mi opinion no es por ser nuevo, ya llevo cierta exp en js), sin embargo te dire la respuesta de manera resumida. **No se puede**. basicamente no se puede porque una promesa  es asincrona, y al ser asincrona ocurririan cosas como por ejemplo que la variable no tenga valor asi la promesa se resuelva con exito y tu le asignes ese valor a la variable.

Comment: Esto de que no tenga valor puede deberse a diferentes razones, por ejemplo el momento de la consulta de la informacion es diferente al momento de la asignacion, teniendo que lidiar con el tiempo, sin embargo te puedo dar una solucion a ese problema pero no con variables.

Answer (score 2):

hay que partir de ciertos conceptos para determinar el porque **NO** se puede sacar el valor de una `Promise` para asignarselo a una variable, aqui estan esos conceptos:

- Asincronismo
- Monohilo
- Tiempo

Con el asincronismo me refiero a que las promesas son **asincronas** mientras que el flujo por defecto en javascript es **sincrono**, cuando `JS` debe ejecutar algo asincrono lo hace, pero al mismo tiempo mientras se esta ejecutando aquello que es asincrono este no bloquea el flujo, por tanto al tratarse de un flujo sincrono este no puede esperar a que el flujo **asincrono** nos de una respuesta para usarla pues hacer esto bloquearia la ejecucion del resto del programa.

Un ejemplo sencillo y corto:

```js
function giveMeANumberInTime(){
  return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
    setTimeout(res, 4000, Math.random());
  });
}

const numero = giveMeANumberInTime();
console.log(numero);
```

Como vemos al ejecutar la funcion asincrona esta no se pausa, y como no ha terminado de ejecutarse el valor asignado no sera el esperado al pasar por el `console.log`.

A esto me refiero con **tiempo**.

Respecto a **monohilo** tiene mas que ver con que javascript es un lenguaje de programacion de un unico hilo, por lo tanto las promesas servirian en este caso para poder que `JS` pueda hacer uso de ese valor cuando este disponible, de esta manera aunque `JS` sea monohilo se le podra ordenar con antelacion que es lo que deseas que el programa haga cuando el valor este listo, asi se soluciona el no poder usar mas de un **thread (hilo)**.

Muy bien, ya habiendo aclarado todo esto. podras haber observado como dije:

> "las promesas servirian en este caso para poder que `JS` pueda hacer
> uso de ese valor cuando este disponible"

Por lo tanto tiene sentido que podamos usar ese valor en algun momento y programar las acciones necesarias. pero entonces como lo hacemos?

Las promesas contienen 2 metodos, uno para obtener el resultado o valor que nos devuelve la promesa al ser resuelta de manera exitosa (`then`) y `catch` que sirve para atrapar el posible error que tengamos.

En tu caso lo único que tienes que hacer es despues del llamado a tu funcion `getEstado` colocar `.then` y por si las moscas .catch de esta manera:

```
function getEstado() {

  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'x-token': this.usuarioService.token,
    'a-token': this.tokenA
  });


  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(`${URL}/agenda/estado/`, {
        headers
      })
      .subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp);

        if (resp['ok']) {

          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }

      });

  });

}

getEstado().then(result =>{
  //Solo tendras disponible la informacion de la promesa aqui dentro de then
  console.log(result);
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

**NOTA:** se le hicieron unos pequeños cambios al código, pues este tenia unos pequeños problemas, por ejemplo:

- Tu agregaste la palabra reservada `async`, pero en tu caso como estas haciendo uso de **Promise, NO** la necesitas, es mucho mejor que todo lo que puedas manejarlo como sincrono se quede como sincrono, en este caso tu funcion igual seria asincrona por la **promise**, pero al colocar el **async** es redundante debido a que `async` hace que la funcion siempre te devuelva una promise de por si asi no retornes nada, por lo tanto estarias retornando una `promise` dentro de una `promise`, lo cual no tiene sentido, eso se soluciona quitando el `async`, el `async` se usa en otros contextos.
- Este ultimo no es un cambio, pero si una observacion, las promises tienen un parametro, en este caso un callback, el callback a su vez recibe 2 parametros (**resolve** y **reject**), ten en cuenta que como no estas usando `reject` no te daras cuenta de que error te puede estar dando la promise, te aconsejo que coloques un bloque `try-catch` para poder atrapar posibles errores y uses el reject en el bloque **catch**.

Comment: function getEstado(): Promise<unknown>
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)   Al agregar la palabra function me aparece ese error

Comment: Si, modifique la respuesta porque me percate de que estabas seguramente utilizando clases, quita la palabra reservada function y si es posible porfavor vuelve a leer la respuesta, para poder ver aquello que ha cambiado...